# Use conditional when on ansible playbook using jinja and a variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

i'm writing a role in order to check if a package is installed on my linux machines (i've many eterogeneus vm with sysvinit or systemd).
So i'm trying first of all to see with systemd if process is running when it is installed and if this failed use sysvinit module to check is process is running on vm where systemd is not installed.
And after that, i'm setting a fact that give "started" as output or "stopped"

```
---
- name: Prendo pacchetti installati
  package_facts:
    manager: "auto"
- name: Check processo se è systemd
  systemd:
    name: "{{ process_name }}"
    state: started
  register: systemd_status
  ignore_errors: true
  when: "'{{ process_name }}' in ansible_facts.packages}}"
- name: Check processo se è sysvinit
  service:
    name: "{{ process_name }}"
    state: started
  register: sysvinit_status
  ignore_errors: true
  when: systemd_status.failed and "'{{ process_name }}' in ansible_facts.packages}}"
- set_fact:
    process_status="
    {% if sysvinit_status.state is not defined or systemd_status.state is not defined %}
      stopped
    {% elif sysvinit_status.state is not defined and systemd_status.state == 'started' %}
      started
    {% elif sysvinit_status.state == 'started' and systemd_status.state is not defined %}
      started
    {% elif sysvinit_status.state == 'started' or systemd_status.state == 'started' %}
      started
    {% else %}
      stopped
    {% endif %}"
```

Comment: `when: process_name in ansible_facts.packages` and `when: systemd_status.failed and process_name in ansible_facts.packages`

Comment: i've that error on task "Check processo se è sysvinit"
`The conditional check 'systemd_status.failed and process_name in ansible_facts.packages' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (systemd_status.failed and process_name in ansible_facts.packages): 'dict object' has no attribute 'failed'`

Comment: You are using `ignore_errors: true` in the task registering it, so, most likely, it errored out instead of failing

Comment: but it doesn't works and i've same errors also if remove `ignore_errors: true` from task before, it seems that last condition `when: systemd_status.failed and process_name in ansible_facts.packages` is not correct

Comment: Do a debug of `systemd_status`, you should see by yourself what it contains.

Comment: that's debug of that var :
`msg:
  - changed: false
    skip_reason: Conditional result was False
    skipped: true`

Comment: So, it is skipped and as you can see, not failed.

Comment: so i need to put also an or if systemd_status.skipped is true right?

Comment: > `when: systemd_status is skipped or systemd_status is failed`

Comment: mm i've to use jinja because i need also put `and process_name in ansible_facts.packages` right?

Comment: [_The `when` clause is a raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces (see group_by_module)_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html).

Comment: And now, read your code again, `systemd_status` will be skipped `when: process_name in ansible_facts.packages`, so if you say:  `when: systemd_status is skipped` this actually is an equivalent to  `when: process_name in ansible_facts.packages`.